# How can I configure NSNumberFormatter to display a decimal part without leading zeros?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I’m using `NSNumberFormatter` to format an `NSDecimalNumber`.

What configuration can I use to display the number `0.012676` as `1`?

**Important: I am *not* trying to round up to 1.0 — I’m trying to round to the hundred place in the decimal, and then strip the preceding zeros and decimal separator.**

---

My current configuration looks something like this:

```
// in a method...

NSDecimalNumber *value = /* retrieve a value like 0.012676 */;
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

// this is the rounding behavior I want
[nf setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven];

[nf setMinimumFractionDigits: 2];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits: 2];

return [nf stringFromNumber: value];
```

which generates an output of:

`.01`

---

With thanks to dasblinkenlight and Twitter friends, the solution is simply to multiply by `100`, and then eliminate the fraction digits:

```
[nf setMultiplier: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 100]];
[nf setMinimumFractionDigits: 0];
[nf setMaximumFractionDigits: 0];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate `N` leading zeros by multiplying by the `N`-th power of ten. Since you are looking for the hundredth place, multiply `0.012676` by `100`, and convert it to an integer.

Comment: Thanks! This was also pointed out to me on Twitter, so I’d like to point that out here to future visitors: https://twitter.com/photar/status/225233393804251136